# Firebase web push notification don't track "opens/notificationclick" count

Tags: next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, firebase-analytics, web-push

In next.js app I receive firebase web push notifications with service-worker in background. When I send web push notification with firebase console, I receive and open notification. But opens/click count always zero. Firebase analytics client doesn't work for service worker. Can you recommend any method to fix this issue?[image]

I didn't found from documentation how update firebase analytics statistics with web push messageId through lovEvent method

Answer (score 0):

You need to log custom events yourself as follows

```
Analytics.logEvent("your_event", parameters: [
  "name": name as NSObject,
  "full_text": text as NSObject
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Analytics primarily focuses on tracking user interactions and events within the browser and app environment to log the notification interactions you will first need to listen to them and then you can create a custom event for analytics.

You can handle the notification click event in your service worker code and in the callback you can log a custom event to Firebase analytics.

Here is an example:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  const notification = event.notification;
  const messageId = notification.data.messageId;

  // Log custom event with Firebase Analytics
  firebase.analytics().logEvent('notification_click', {
    messageId: messageId
  });

  // ... Your other notification click handling logic
});
```